# Updating a database from selected row in another form

Tags: c#, database

I am having issues updating a selected row on a datagridview that pulls from a database in another form.
I used this to get the information from the datagridview into the textboxes on the other form:

```
    private void updateAppointmentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            UpdateAppointment updateAppointment = new UpdateAppointment();
            updateAppointment.mainFormObject = this;
            updateAppointment.customerIdBox.Text = appointmentCalendar.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            updateAppointment.customerNameBox.Text = appointmentCalendar.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            updateAppointment.typeBox.Text = appointmentCalendar.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            updateAppointment.startTimeBox.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(appointmentCalendar.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
            updateAppointment.endTimeBox.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(appointmentCalendar.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());

            updateAppointment.Show();



        MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection(SqlUpdater.conString);
        MySqlCommand updateCmd = new MySqlCommand();

        updateCmd.Connection = c;
        c.Open();
        updateCmd.CommandText = $"UPDATE customer SET customerName = '{customerNameBox.Text}'";
        updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        c.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Appointment Updated");
```

I figure its the SQL query, but not sure how to limit it to JUST the information on the selected row. Right now, it'll update everyone on the datagridview and database.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

I've tried putting 
    MainForm.appointmentCalendar.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

as WHERE in the SQL query, but it returns an "object reference is required" error.

Comment: See my two form project at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: piotrb92: That should work, and instead of being able to update the ID and name of the person, just update the times....let me give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a column with unique customer ID, then in your query you want

```
Update customer SET customerName = '{customerNameBox.Text}' where customerID = 'UniqueID'
```

----- (whatever the ID that you are trying to update is)

probably something like `int.Parse(otherDataGrid.selectedRows[0].Cells["ID"].Value.ToString())`

@edit

I don't really understand what you're trying to say. You might want to try with parameteres. this would be your query:

```
Update appointment set type = @type, start = @start, end = @end where customerId = @id
```

then before you execute the command you say:

```
updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", typeBox.Text);
```

and do that for all other parameters too.
Also make sure that your text boxes are not empty, because they most likely are if your query is deleting the data (maybe it's updating it with an empty string)

Comment: Ok ran it with: WHERE customerId = '{customerIdBox.Text}'
I did change the query to:
    UPDATE appointment SET type = '{typeBox.Text}', start = 
    '{startTimeBox.Value.ToString()}', end = '{endTimeBox.Value.ToString()}' WHERE 
    customerId = '{customerIdBox.Text}'

And now, it deletes the start/end times AND sets the type to the same thing where on all records (with the same type)....

Comment: look at my edited answer, I couldn't post it as a comment

Comment: Using the parameters works, but I think part of my problem lies in the database itself.
There are 2 entries under the "type column", so if I am updating it, then it's going to change it for everyone.